# What does Android do when laying out components if there is not enough space?

Tags: android, android-layout

Newbie question here, but I'm struggling to find the answer.

When laying out components, clearly if android can fit all the components on the screen while respecting all the requested attributes (height, margin etc), then it will do that.

But what if there is not enough room on the screen for everything? I had thought that it would simply put what it could on the screen starting at 0,0, and then have horizontal or vertical scrollbars for the rest.

However, that's not what I'm seeing, but I can't figure out what I *am* seeing. For example, when I try to view the following layout on my phone, the text has disappeared off the top of the screen (I can get this by turning the phone to landscape mode where there is obviously less available height).

What gives? How is android determining how to lay out these components and where to place the centre of the screen?

Many thanks!

EDIT: It looks like the problem has to do with me using so many dp values that mean that there's no way for everything to fit on the screen. I've fixed my immediate problem by using layout 'weight' to scale my components proportionally to the screen rather than trying to specify absolute sizes. I'm still curious why the layout code would choose to push my text off the top though - perhaps it priortises dp values?

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:text="@string/TextView1Text2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:onClick="@string/Button1OnClick"
            android:text="@string/Button1Text" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/bla"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/blank_1024_200" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Scrollbars only exist on views like ScrollView, HorizontalScrollView, and NestedScrollView. Android documentation has a section on screen size compatibility: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility Historically Android developers design and only test on what they intend to support - see the many apps with phone layouts on tablets.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Ah thank you for your useful response. That guide looks very useful.